# How to know UILocalNotification remaining time before fires?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I would like to know remaining time before `UILocalNotification` fires and then show it in some `UIabel` in real time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Notification has property **fireDate** - The date and time when the system should deliver the notification.
So you can use it and current date for calculation remained time.

Comment: So, for example, every minute, I need to get current Date&Time and calculate remaining time? Can I use **timeIntervalSinceNow**?

Comment: Yes, you should implement timer and recalculate remaining time every time when it fires. 
I think you can use **timeIntervalSinceNow**, but I never used this method for date from future

Answer (score 0):

Following two methods available to get the Registered LocalNotifications, get the Object of it and access FireDate, and calculate your time

To get all the notifications

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

To get particular notification object if you know Which object to get.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:yourNOtificationObject];
```